# React Native - Packager randomly crashing, Windows 10 + android avd

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, windows-10, android-virtual-device

Using `react-native` on Windows 10 + Android Virtual Device emulator. Hot reloading is turned on and everything works just fine.

The cycle of code editing and reloading works for the first several edits, and after some edits (different number of edit each time), the packager crashes with the following error message:

```
[Hot Module Replacement] Sending HMR update to client (14:45:24:193)
[Hot Module Replacement] Sending HMR update to client (14:45:24:195)
[Hot Module Replacement] Client connected
[2:45:25 PM] <START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false
[2:45:25 PM] <END>   request:/index.android.map?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false (2660ms)
[2:45:25 PM] <END>   request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false (252ms)
[Hot Module Replacement] Client connected
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'c:\dev\music\index.android.js___jb_old___'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"c:\\dev\\music\\index.android.js___jb_old___"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'c:\dev\music\index.android.js___jb_old___'
    at Error (native)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Some details about the project:

- OS: Windows 10
- Android SDK Manager Revision 25.1.7
- Virtual Device configured exactly as described here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/react-native-android-studio-avd-windows.png
- Running the packager using `react-native run android` from Administrator `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling '**Safe Write**' (`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings, 'Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary files first)`) - does it help?

See also [Windows & Android: react native server crashes very often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701115/windows-android-react-native-server-crashes-very-often/38831876#38831876)