# Windows & Android: react native server crashes very often

Tags: react-native

```
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat '...\.idea\workspace.xml___jb_old___'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"...\.idea\\workspace.xml___jb_old___"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'app\.idea\workspace.xml___jb_old___'
    at Error (native)
```

After that I should again do:

```
npm start
```

How to resolve this quite annoying problem?

Answer (score 24):

I think it's the problem of 'save write', I am using Webstorm, uncheck "File->Settings->System Settings->sychronization->use safe write"  to see if it helps you.

Comment: YES, I think this should be the accepted answer.
@pvllnspk is as far as I can see also using WebStorm (or a similar IDE).

Comment: Works for Intellij IDEA as well

Comment: The "use safe write" option has been renamed to "Back up files before saving".

Answer (score 24):

**Solution:**

How to fix the file permissions, after loading end
`react-native start`

First, Go to android folder

`cd android`

Now clean the project...

`gradlew clean //for Mac users, change gradlew to ./gradlew`

Now run the build process again in the root folder

`cd ..
react-native run-android`

Comment: @p-bizouard I'm happy to hear it! thanks for voting up. Which platform are you using? Windows / Mac?

Comment: On Windows, your comands are right with basic cmd.exe utilty.

Comment: Great! It fixed my issue after struggling for 2 days. Thank you!

Comment: In my case, I used .\gradlew clean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75578833/5509892

Answer (score 7):

Basically it looks like windows bug on react packager. When you disable Hot Reloading, it should be stopped. If not, can you try "npm cache clean" before run "react-native run-android", please? Also you can try to run on administrator. If these are not working, maybe it's about Antivirus app.

Also can you add ".idea" folder to your github ignore file to try? And are you trying to run it from Webstorm (or any eclipse-based platform) directly or terminal?

Comment: I run it from Android Studio

Comment: it crashes every time when I build java code, build folder changes -> server crashes

Comment: Tried: disable Hot Reloading,  npm cache clean, run on administrator - no luck(

Comment: I got this error after executing react-native run-android. I was using default emulator  I started genymotion and error disappeared.At least for now :) React native + windows are full of suprises.

Answer (score 2):

Closing SourceTree did the trick for me. Once I pushed my changes to the repository also crashed server (I suppose GitKraken has the same effect).

Comment: Both answer work toogether, uncheck use safe write and close SourceTree

Answer (score 0):

The best temporary fix I found for this was that when you do `react-native run-android`, look out for the React Package Manager and as soon as it opens, close it and wait until the progress of `react-native run-android` says `BUILD SUCCEEDED` and then open another cmd in the same Directory of your react-native project and do `npm start`. If the server crashes again or you get any error, you can just do `npm start` again and continue your work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause can be if any of npm server(cmd terminal window) whether it is your project's sever or other project then close it and now you will not get this error

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experimenting with expo and I am finding this behaviour whenever I try to edit files.

The mentioned solution by @user6795391 worked for me however at some point the setting in Webstorm changed to `Back up files before saving`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/system-settings.html

Obviously please consider the implications of disabling this!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

It worked for me

Answer (score -5):

use

`$ react-native start`

І hope it works