# React Native - Constant errors like "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat ..."

Tags: react-native

I am fairly new to React Native, and it appears my app is crashing prior to executing my primary app code, but I cannot figure out where.  In VSCode, I see the following in my Output:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'c:\Dev\myapp\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\com\bumptech\glide\integration\okhttp'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (c:\Dev\myapp\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:176:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'c:\\Dev\\myapp\\android\\app\\build\\generated\\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\\debug\\r\\com\\bumptech\\glide\\integration\\okhttp'
```

I'm trying to figure out how to determine where this is coming from, and how to debug errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I also got same Error while working with react-native on windows.

I am not sure the root cause of this error but following the steps below helps me to solve the problem.

1. On Android Studio go to  **File>invalidate Caches/Restart**
2. Terminate local react native server
3. Then Run `npx react-native start --reset-cache` and `npm run android`

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem on Windows 10. Seems that the node watcher modules of sane and metro throw an error if other programs access a file when they try to check for changes. Other programs may be a virus scanner, git, java, gcc, etc.
At the end I patched the NodeWatcher.js and node_watcher.js files to ignore the error.
Using **yarn patch-package package-name** stored the necessary changes in my project.
Example changes in NodeWatcher.js:

```
  processChange(dir, event, file) {
const fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
const relativePath = path.join(path.relative(this.root, dir), file);
// Use isIgnorableFileError to ignore EPERM errors on Windows machines
// when watching the file system. E.g. http://bitstopixels.blogspot.com/2017/04/react-native-windows-10-eperm-operation.html
fs.lstat(fullPath, (error, stat) => {
  if (!isIgnorableFileError(error)) {
    this.emit('error', error);
  } else if (!error && stat.isDirectory()) {
    // win32 emits usless change events on dirs.
    if (event !== 'change') {
      this.watchdir(fullPath);

      if (
        common.isFileIncluded(
          this.globs,
          this.dot,
          this.doIgnore,
          relativePath
        )
      ) {
        this.emitEvent(ADD_EVENT, relativePath, stat);
      }
    }
  } else if (!error) {
    const registered = this.registered(fullPath);

    if (error && error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      this.unregister(fullPath);
      this.stopWatching(fullPath);
      this.unregisterDir(fullPath);

      if (registered) {
        this.emitEvent(DELETE_EVENT, relativePath);
      }
    } else if (registered) {
      this.emitEvent(CHANGE_EVENT, relativePath, stat);
    } else {
      if (this.register(fullPath)) {
        this.emitEvent(ADD_EVENT, relativePath, stat);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
function isIgnorableFileError(error) {
  return (
    error === null || // Allow usage for no error too
    error.code === 'ENOENT' || // Workaround Windows node issue #4337.
    (error.code === 'EPERM' && platform === 'win32')
  );
}
```

so that I can use the isIgnorableFileError function in processChange.

I'm not sure if this fixes all issues, but for me it worked. Now I can build and run my app without metro crashes.

Comment: do you have an example project in github that has your patch code and some basic expo app?

Comment: Unfortunately not. And it is not an expo app.

Answer (score 4):

worked solution #1

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
```

worked solution #2

```
npx react-native run-android
```

after complete giving you the **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** message. start metro server again

```
npx react-native start
```

press `r`

resources

http://bitstopixels.blogspot.com/2017/04/react-native-windows-10-eperm-operation.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43217182/5509892

Answer (score 3):

The solution here worked for me: http://bitstopixels.blogspot.com/2017/04/react-native-windows-10-eperm-operation.html

```
cd <app_root>/android
./gradlew clean
```

I also had to disable 'hermes' in <app_root>/android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

I got this error many time while working with react native.

Follow these simple steps to get out of this error:

1. On Android Studio, Go to **File > invalidate Caches..(Restart)**
2. **Terminate server** you have started by npm start
3. Run following commands respectively.

> npx react-native start --reset-cache

> npx react-native run-android

Mostly my error get resolved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Android folder using

`cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug`

Go back to the main folder by

`cd ..`

Now run `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: I've tried this several times, but this doesn't get it.

Comment: I keep adding implementation lines to build.gradle, but then a new (very similar error) pops up

Comment: Latest one: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'c:\Dev\myapp\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\localbroadcastmanager\R.java'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (c:\Dev\myapp\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:176:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'c:\\Dev\\myapp\\android\\app\\build\\generated\\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\\debug\\r\\androidx\\localbroadcastmanager\\R.java'
}

Answer (score 0):

Ended up reverting back after a massive upgrade and then upgraded a bit more slowly.  I've eliminated these errors thus far, but I haven't completed the upgrade.  Will post back if I find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

cd <app_root>/android
./gradlew clean

Copy Pasting this command worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error, while attempting to run the application after cloning it from GitHub.

**Error:**

> EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat <directory_path>

I took the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Delete the **node modules** and **package.lock.json**
2. Open your project directory in **cmd** prompt as administrator.
3. Install the node modules again, using command: **npm install**
4. Clean your **gradle** file in android folder by running command:
   **cd android && gradlew clean**
5. Now, go to project directory using the command: **cd..**
6. Open **metro.config.js** file and write the below code there:

```
var getBlacklistRE = function getBlacklistRE(){ return new RegExp("(.*\\android\\.*|.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\\]react[\\\\]dist[\\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$"); }

module.exports = { 
  resolver: { 
    "blacklistRE": getBlacklistRE(), 
  }
};
```

7. Now, install the **npx** globally: **npm install -g npx**
8. Run your application using command: **npx react-native start**

9. Press **a** for run it in android

**Note: Dont push metro.config.js in github repo.**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, for me default port (=8081) to run react native was occupied by other application.

Check default port 8081 is free or not
open cmd as administrator run below command

````
```netstat -ano | findstr "8081"```
````

If above command shows there some task is running in port 8081 (it will give you pip_number too), Now you have two option

1. kill the task running on port 8081 by below command

   `taskkill /F /PID pid_number`
2. Run your RN application on different port, by changing in package.json
   inside script block change below lines -->

```
    "android": "react-native run-android --port=9988",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --port=9988",
    "start": "react-native start --port=9988"
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it happens when new dependencies are installed. So, After every installation you should clean your gradle.
For this just copy and paste the following command in your `package.json` file under `scripts` section:

```
"clean": "cd android && gradlew clean && cd ../",
```

and run the command `yarn clean` or `npm run clean` or `npx react-native clean` after every new installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same Error

**Because:** when we delete any folder from any project or delete the whole project folder. The VS Code or other development environment has the nesessary permission to access and modify the file in your project.

**Clean Build:**
Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. In a React Native project, you can do this by running the following commands in your project directory:

1. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
2. `cd android`
3. `./gradlew clean`
4. `cd ..`
5. `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Just like [@cb_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16354232/cb-dev) mentioned the best approach is:

1. On Android Studio go to File>invalidate Caches/Restart
2. Terminate local react native server

After following those steps delete then delete the build folder in the android path `android/build`.

3. Then Run npx react-native start --reset-cache and npm run android