# React Native Drawer Navigation v6.6.2 Issue with React Native Reanimated v3.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have successfully installed ReactNative Drawer navigation, but it only works once. From the beginning, the hamburger menu is not functional but I can swipe the drawer out and when I press any navigation item, it takes me to that screen. But after that, it stops working.

I followed the official guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation

HELP Please!!!

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

---

This is index.js, the entry file:

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

---

And this is my App.js file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, View} from 'react-native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems like same issue with this [https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11391](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11391). You may try downgrade `react-native-reanimated` package and try again.

Comment: I tried downgrading it to 2.12 but then the build failed... which version to downgrade are you referring to?

Comment: The post said it is compatible with v3.1.0.

Comment: Should be cache issue, try clear cache to fix it [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444463/20002061](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444463/20002061).

Comment: It worked!  .... if you want to answer the question I will accept it. Yet it's a simple trick... Wonder why 3.2.0 is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@react-navigation/drawer` v6.6.2 is now **incompatible** with `react-native-reanimated` v3.2.0.
Issue is raise in github too. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11391.

Solution is downgrade `react-native-reanimated` to **v3.1.0**. Incompatible issue need to be fixed by package provider, so we need to wait until next release.

Changing package version may cause cache issue, please try again with clear cache.